# TAB functionality in SE when editing code -- What's the UX view on it?

Tags: keyboard, editor, tabindex

***Disclaimer: [I'm cross-posting this question from Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234533/tab-functionality-in-se-when-editing-code-what-do-you-prefer) to get input from the UX fanatics here.***

---

I've seen people complain about not been able to use <kbd>`TAB`</kbd> to format code in SE. There are many fixes such as:

- format code in a text editor, then insert
- use <kbd>`CTRL`</kbd> + <kbd>`K`</kbd>
- use <kbd>`SPACE x 4`</kbd> newb

[The request to implement tab formatting functionality has been denied by SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234533/tab-functionality-in-se-when-editing-code-what-do-you-prefer), and refuted on the claim that this would damage <kbd>`TAB`</kbd>'s native functionality in the browser.

As a developer who focuses on UX, I disagree, on the grounds that I believe that when editing code, <kbd>`TAB`</kbd> is expected by most users to create a tab, not jump to the next element in the page.

**Do you think that giving <kbd>TAB</kbd> formatting functionality will improve UX?**

Comment: Should this be on the UX Main site?

Comment: I've moved this to the main site. While it is about Stack Exchange software, the general concept and answers are going to be about the User Experience practices, and therefore useful to a wider variety of people outside of just those interested in how Stack Exchange operates.

Answer (score 4):

### I suggest enabling <kbd>TAB</kbd>'s formating **`<code>` between code tags. `</code>`**

---

`<code> If I were to hit TAB now, it would result in 4 spaces. </code> But not outside of the tags.`

### Advantages

---

- **Avoids a keyboard trap.** Impaired users can easily avoid using `<code>` tags, and if they do use them, navigating away from them can be done with arrow keys.
- **It doesn't affect the editor's primary functionality.** It targets users who have searched the tab issue and found that tabs work for formatting! `<code> between code tags :) </code>`
- **The code for the feature is actually simple and fairly short.** it can be done in just 365 characters [365 bytes]. [Credit 100% to dandavis for this solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2317490/dandavis)

### Try Before You Buy

---

**Go ahead.** Put it into the JS console of any Stack Exchange [question page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), and `<code> use tabs between code tags! </code>`. [Or try the JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9fYyU/)

```
$("textarea").keydown(function (e) {
    var t = this.value,
    n = this.selectionStart,
    r = [t.slice(0, n), t.slice(n)];
    if (e.keyCode == 9 && t.indexOf("</code>", n) != -1 && t.lastIndexOf("<code>",
    n) != -1) {
        this.value = r.join("   ");
        this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = n + 1;
        e.preventDefault()
    }
})
```

Comment: I didn't really think about it, but I didn't format my answer to fit the question. I just posed a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the primary reason for browser tabbing through elements is for keyboard/non pointer device users. How would these users navigate out of code area if traditional browser tab functionality was taken away?

Would it be possible to use a key combination along with the tab key to insert tabs? (alt+tab?)

Obviously the solution would need to be validated to make sure it doesn't clash with any browser defaults for other actions. For example shift+tab typically moves back through tabbable elements.

Comment: Make tabs work as 4 spaces between `<code>` tags. No one needs to or commonly uses the code tags. 4 spaces or back-tics cover code normally, but if a user finds himself wanting to write a fairly detailed code example, he can set up code tags.

Comment: The code required to do this is actually fairly simple and short.

Comment: Not really `alt+tab` switches to the next open window, `ctrl+tab` switches to the next [tab] and you already mentioned `shift+tab`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, giving <kbd>Tab</kbd> functionality what it is expected to do would improve UX. If someone is explicitly editing code they would expect that pressing Tab will do a tab indent, or 4 spaces instead of tabbing over to Post Your Answer. They might <kbd>Tab</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> for a newline, and then instead of doing that, I'll posted my unfinished answer instead.

[image: Tab Mockup Comparison]

In the rightmost one, I'm writing code in the editor (I forgot to add code tags in this case, but it doesn't matter), and if I were to hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and in the middle of me attempting to type code, it goes right down to the Submit Answer area.

In the leftmost one, I am writing code, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> and it doesn't interrupt my flow. The only problem is that you have to click the Submit Answer button, but I've always clicked it with a mouse, as it interrupts me and makes me think if I answered it to the best of my ability (which in SE's case, is usually a good thing). Plus, I get to tell everyone about the [awesomeness of jQuery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/238126).

Comment: This is really just your individual opinion. You mention a lot of 'I' and 'me' here, but you are but one person. A small use-case that involves you writing code in a text field is made slightly less convenient because you can't use the TAB button in the way you can in a dedicated editor application. What about all the other web users out there? The users who browse with keyboard only? They'd be stuck in that text field forever! And those who require screen-readers to access the web? How would they know what's going on?

Comment: @JonW [Shift + Space] == Space x 4 -- What's the harm in that?

Answer (score 0):

### The key combo <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> does the trick

---

[See the feature request on Meta SE.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234662/should-shift-spacebar-create-a-tab-indent-in-se)

While using `<code></code>` to target the tab easy formatting is a bit rough around the edges, I think you'll find that **<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>** offers a shortcut that appears to have no downside.

### Advantages

---

- **No keyboard trap.** It doesn't affect Tab Order in any way.
- **Doesn't break anything.** No native functionality in any browser nor OS (that was the issue with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> in Windows 8) uses this key combination.
- **Doesn't require an interface change.** This solution is silent, and therefore can be utilized by anyone who wishes to use the functionality without bothering anyone who doesn't.
- **The code to do this is minimal.** Like my other suggestion, the solution is barely over 300 bytes added to the site. Again, credit to dandavis for this code.

### Try Before You Buy

---

**Go ahead.** Put it into the JS console of any Stack Exchange question page, and use **<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>** for your formatting tabs. [Or try the JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9fYyU/2/)

```
$("textarea").keydown(function (e) {
    var t = this.value,
        n = this.selectionStart,
        r = [t.slice(0, n), t.slice(n)];
    if (e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 32) {
        this.value = r.join("   ");
        this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = n + 1;
        e.preventDefault()
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Vision impaired users need to be able to tab to different navigation points (most would like to submit their answer after typing it in), so no this should not be the default setting.

Using other key combinations like: <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> is not widely standardized but easy to learn and would not hinder keyboard navigation, so this is a good compromise for a default setting.

For sites in SE (or any site with user configurable settings) the tabbing behavior should be configurable in user settings.